# Is ViaBTC the only public Bitcoin Cash pool?

Tags: mining-pools, bitcoin-cash

Is ViaBTC the only public Bitcoin Cash pool?
I have spent hours in searching but could not find another one.

As the price of Bitcoin Cash surges, a lot of people want to mine it.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: https://bcc.suprnova.cc/ -this is the second pool which I found

Answer (score 1):

No, http://pool.Bitcoin.com also offers BCH mining as far as i'm concerned, see

https://news.bitcoin.com/bitcoin-com-pool-members-now-have-the-option-to-mine-bitcoin-cash/

Which is https://stratum.bcc.pool.bitcoin.com:3333/

Answer (score 0):

Coinfoundry is running a Bitcoin Cash Pool as well: https://coinfoundry.org/pool/bch